# LibGDX - How can i change the Background of a TextButton?

Tags: java, android, json, libgdx

I want to change the background of a TextButton in LibGDX.
Here is a snippet of my json Skin file:

```
  com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.TextButton$TextButtonStyle: {
    default: {down: btnNormal, up: btnNormal, font: brokendetroit-font, fontColor: black, pressedOffsetX: 3, pressedOffsetY: -3}
    green: {down: btnEnabled, up: btnEnabled, font: brokendetroit-font, fontColor: green, pressedOffsetX: 5, pressedOffsetY: -5}
    red: {down: btnDisabled, up: btnDisabled, font: brokendetroit-font, fontColor: green, pressedOffsetX: 5, pressedOffsetY: -5}
    close: {down: btnClose, up: btnClose, font: brokendetroit-font, fontColor: black, pressedOffsetX: 3, pressedOffsetY: -3}
  },
```

When I'm creating a Textbutton i can set the "**StyleName**"

`TextButton txtBtn = new TextButton("text..", skin, "default");`

I want to change the style of the skin, but the `setSkin()` method doesn't provide a parameter for the Stylename, just for the skin...

example:
`txtBtn.setSkin(skin);`

but i want this:
`txtBtn.setSkin(skin, "green");`

How can I change the stylename?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The skin object you created offers this functionality. You can do `skin.get("yourStyle", Class<t>)`. So in the case you want to change the style of your text button:

```
txtBtn.setStyle = skin.get("green", TextButtonStyle.class);
```